# Facebook FQL returns invalid counts

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am using FQL to find share counts of shares on my pages as follows:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT%20url%2C%20normalized_url%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%2C%20comment_count%2C%20total_count%2C%20commentsbox_count%2C%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Fgoout.cz%2Fcs%2Fkoncerty%2Fpraha%2Fcharlie-slavik-band%2Frbvi%2F'

This URL has my internal statistics was viewed just a few times and yet, it has been shared and commented more than 50x.

This is happening with many of my URLs and I don't know what is wrong.

Do you think that these numbers are real? What do they stand for?

Comment: Look at your URL in the Graph API explorer. You can only get these counts for the canonical URL.

Comment: Well, the URL is cannonical and the Graph API explorer show the same thing: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20url%2C%20normalized_url%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%2C%20comment_count%2C%20total_count%2C%20commentsbox_count%2C%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Fgoout.cz%2Fcs%2Fkoncerty%2Fpraha%2Fcharlie-slavik-band%2Frbvi%2F' - there is no way that this url was liked 40 times.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without a deep dive. I can see you aren't explicitly embedding open graph metadata in your pages and you're using the deprecated `sharer.php` endpoint. These might be contributing to the issue. Is another page incorrectly listing this as canonical? Have you checked your insights on this page?